# can i use .net to get email address from exchange (not AD) using username?

Tags: .net, exchange-server

is there a way to get at the exchange data store? i want to pull the email address of users in my c#/ .net application - preferably using user names.

i am doing this in AD but the email addresses in AD are wrong and i get bounce backs. seeing how unreliable AD is with Emails i need to go to exchange as my only saving grace.

any clue?

Comment: Doesn't exchange store all the email addresses in AD? They're editable from any machine with the exchange AD management stuff installed I think.

Comment: it cant be- cause pulling an email from AD shows a different email then pulling the email of the same user from exchange.

Comment: there has to be a way to get the data exchange has its hands on.

Comment: Oh OK. How do you pull an email from exchange then that's different from AD? From powershell somehow? (If so you can use the same .NET interface it's using.) Whenever I've edited email addresses in Exchange I've used the AD interface.

Comment: It is DEFINITELY in AD. If you have a simple single forest it's gonna be one of the proxyAddress (multivalued attributes). The primary one has SMTP in caps and is normally as the same as the mail (singlevalued attributed). With a multiforest Exchange Resource Forest, things get....more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I am mainly a PowerShell user but when I do this I utilise the System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher .NET method, like this:

```
# Bind to OU Container
$OUPath = "LDAP://OU=SomeContainer,DC=domain,DC=com"
$SearchOU = [ADSI]$OUPath

# Use System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher to Find objects in Container
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($SearchOU)

# Filter results
$LDAPQueryFilter = "(&(HomeMDB=*)(mail=*)(objectClass=user))"
$Searcher.Filter = $LDAPQueryFilter

# Return results
$SearchResults = $Searcher.FindAll()
```

As someone else mentioned you want to enumerate the ProxyAddresses collection which is an AD field with a multi-valued property (it's an array of strings basically).

Hope this helps a bit?

Answer (score 0):

As the other responses have indicated, all versions of Exchange through Exchange 2010 read and write user data directly in Active Directory.  There is no other repository.  Even Exchange Online reads and writes data to AD under the covers.  I would recommend double-checking AD attribute you're using to read the email address.

If you would prefer to avoid the AD query directly, you may use EWS to make the AD query:
http://vivekiyer.net/2010/07/17/querying-the-global-address-list-gal-via-exchange-web-services-ews/